# Using fonts in custom signatureAppearance signatures with iText7 breaks PDF/A conformance?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to create signed PDFs from PDF/A-1A input files, the output must preserve the conformance level.

The signatures have to be added with a customized appearance.

If I do it along the code lines below, everything works on the signature side, and the signature is diplayed correctly and verifies OK.

But the PDF/A conformance is broken by the embedded fonts that do not contain the required toUnicode CMAPs.

```
PdfADocument pdf = ... the doc to be signed
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfReader reader = pdf.getReader();
PrivateKey privateKey = ...
Provider signatureProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Certificate[] signChain = ...
PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(reader, buffer, true);
PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance();
signatureAppearance.setReuseAppearance(false);
 signatureAppearance.setPageNumber(pdf.getNumberOfPages());
 pdfSigner.setFieldName("Custom Signature");
 float margin = 35;        
 Rectangle pageSize = pdf.getLastPage().getMediaBox();
 Rectangle signaturePosition = new Rectangle(pageSize.getLeft()+margin,
                                                pageSize.getBottom()+margin,
                                                pageSize.getWidth()-2*margin, 
                                                (pageSize.getHeight()-2*margin)/3);


    // need to do this before creating any *Canvas object, else the pageRect will be null and the signature invisible
    signatureAppearance.setPageRect(signaturePosition);

PdfFont regularFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/path/to/truetypefile-regular.ttf", "ISO-8859-1", true);
PdfFont boldFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/path/to/truetypefile-bold.ttf", "ISO-8859-1", true);

int fontSize = 10;

PdfFormXObject n0 = signatureAppearance.getLayer0();
PdfCanvas n0Canvas = new PdfCanvas(n0, pdfSigner.getDocument());
PdfFormXObject n2 = signatureAppearance.getLayer2();
Canvas n2Canvas = new Canvas(n2, pdfSigner.getDocument());
if(regularFont != null) {
    n2Canvas.setFont(regularFont);
    n0Canvas.setFontAndSize(regularFont, fontSize);
}
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create("/path/to/image.png");
Image image = new Image(imageData);
n2Canvas.add(image);

String layer2Text = ... some lines of text containing newlines and some simple markdown
String[] paragraphs = layer2text.split("\n\n");
for (String text : paragraphs) {
    boolean bold = false;
    if(text.startsWith("[bold]")) {
        bold = true;
        text = text.replaceFirst("^\\s*\\[bold\\]\\s*", "");
    }

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);
    p.setFontSize(fontSize);
    if(bold) {
        p.setFont(boldFont);
    }
    n2Canvas.add(p);
}
...   pdfSigner.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS);

PrivateKeySignature externalSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(privateKey, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, signatureProvider.getName());
BouncyCastleDigest externalDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

pdfSigner.signDetached(externalDigest, externalSignature, signChain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

So I assume there is something missing there. The fonts that get embedded to not conform to PDF/A because they miss the ToUnicode CMAP key.
Another error from pdf-tools validator says:
"The value of the key Encoding is Difference but must be WinAnsiEncoding or MacRomanEncoding." Which seems to be the same problem.

The signature itself is OK and visibly, styling and image in place as should be. It's just the fonts that seem to not be OK.

Comment: Can you also share a sample signed PDF for analysis? You indicate several ellipses which might have an influence, and so might the original PDF you sign.

Comment: The input file: [SignatureTestDocument-sig.pdf](https://xfer.ch/files/SignatureTestDocument-sig.pdf), the signed file: [SignatureTestDocument-sig-certification.pdf](https://xfer.ch/files/SignatureTestDocument-sig-certification.pdf). Please note that the input file is already signed by another application (which embedded the Albany font). The BAAAAA+LiberationSerif-Bold and CAAAAA+LiberationSerif were embedded by the Producer, LibreOffice.

Comment: Indeed there are certain shortcomings concerning the PDF/A-1a conformance in the signed document you provide. I've seen, though, that many fixes and improvements have been implemented in the iText development code. Thus, I'll try and use your code with the current 7.0.1-SNAPSHOT to see whether the situation has improved.

Comment: You might want to try `PdfEncodings.WINANSI` as font encoding instead of "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: @mkl Hey, thanks, so cool ... While `PdfEncodings.WINANSI` does not exist in iText7, `PdfName.WinAnsiEncoding.getValue()` does the trick! See [SignatureTestDocument-sig-certification-winansi.pdf](https://xfer.ch/files/SignatureTestDocument-sig-certification-winansi.pdf) for the resulting file. +1

Comment: *"`PdfEncodings.WINANSI` does not exist in iText7,"* - But it does exist, cf. `com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings.WINANSI` in the com.itextpdf:io artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger for the violation of the PDF/A compliance is the way the fonts are created here

```
PdfFont regularFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/path/to/truetypefile-regular.ttf", "ISO-8859-1", true);
PdfFont boldFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/path/to/truetypefile-bold.ttf", "ISO-8859-1", true);
```

or even more specifically the encoding parameter `"ISO-8859-1"` used therein.

The PDF/A-1 specification requires:

> #### 6.3.7 Character encodings
>
> All non-symbolic TrueType fonts shall specify *MacRomanEncoding* or *WinAnsiEncoding* as the value of the
>   **Encoding** entry in the font dictionary. All symbolic TrueType fonts shall not specify an **Encoding** entry in the
>   font dictionary, and their font programs' “cmap” tables shall contain exactly one encoding.

The use of the encoding parameter `"ISO-8859-1"` caused a neither *MacRomanEncoding* nor *WinAnsiEncoding* to be specified as the value of the
**Encoding** entry in the font dictionary. Instead the value is a dictionary containing only a *Differences* entry containing an explicit mapping.

Depending on the PDF/A validator this may result in different error messages.

---

For (as I assume) historic reasons there are a few different encoding parameter values during font creation which cause iText to use *WinAnsiEncoding*:

- `""`
- `PdfEncodings.WINANSI` (`== "Cp1252"`)
- `"winansi"` (case-insensitive)
- `"winansiencoding"` (case-insensitive)

The OP used `PdfName.WinAnsiEncoding.getValue()` which returns a string matching the latest option.

---

While this indicates that iText can be used to properly sign PDF/A documents, a specific `PDFASigner` class enforcing conformance probably should be introduced.

Comment: From version itext7 7.1.3, PdfSigner constructor checks if the PDF declares PdfAConformanceLevel. If so, it creates an internal PdfADocument instead of a PdfDocument.